# Parse a string containing a large integer in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, csv

I am having trouble parsing a data set from a .txt file into an Excel file (.csv) in Python.

The source code looks like:

```
fin = open(filename,'r')
reader = csv.reader(fin)
for line in reader:
    list = str(line).split()
    print list3
    print str(list3[1])
```

My data sample looks like:

```
10134.5 -123 9.9527
```

And Python screen output looks like this

```
["['10134.5", '-123', '9.9527,"']" 

-131.7000
```

So I'm assuming `list3[1]` is a `float` or a number at this moment, which cause some overflow because 100,000 is large than it can hold...
Do you know how to let Python treat it as a `string` not a `integer`..

Comment: Where does `list3` get a value?

Comment: Should that be `print list` and `print str(list[1])` instead of `list3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
You do not need to split, or to cast to string... numbers inside the list are strings.

fin = open(filename,'r')
reader = csv.reader(fin)
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

**output**

['10134.5', '-123', '9.9527']

Comment: Oh it actually helped!